# Handle exceptions in OnApplicationError event in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have Web API application and **I want to handle exceptions in Global.asax** **in OnApplicationError event** as I did for usual web apps. But for some reasons when error throws, it doesn't fire OnApplicationError event. I think it is default mechanism of Web API in ASP.NET. *Do you know if I can handle such errors in Global.asax?*

I found a solution for me - **I created an exception filter attribute** and handle exceptions there. I just wondering if I can do the same in global.asax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register your exception filter in the Global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterWebApiFilters(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleExceptionAttribute());
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
         RegisterWebApiFilters(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters);
    }
}
```